# By clicking the header.php inside the index.php, how can the cotent.php will change to cotent1.php?

Tags: php, html, menu

Inside the index.php, it includes the 3 following pages

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'content.php'; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

For the header.php, it is a menu like the attached pic [menu and content pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCafo.png).

Now the problem is after I click on the menu, I want the **content.php**  change to another page such as **content1.php** . Or else the content inside the content.php change. How could this possibly happen inside my index.php when the **header.php** is clicked and the **content.php** will change to **content1.php** or **its content inside the content.php will be changed** to what I want.

Please advise and my email is andybusy@hotmail.com.  Thank you.

Regards

Andy

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php if(isset($_GET['pagename']))
{
 $pagename=$_GET['pagename'].'.php';
}
else
{
$pagename='content.php';
}
?>
<?php include $pagename; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

this is your link Nev bar

```
<a href="index.php?pagename=content">page1</a>
<a href="index.php?pagename=content1">page2</a>
<a href="index.php?pagename=content2">page3</a>
```